# Draw a wave line

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm trying to make a copy of the bubble trouble game in C#.
I need to create the game in windows form application.

I use Graphics for the drawing.
In the bubble trouble original game the arrow is moving like wave, and not a straight line and i can't figure out how to do this.

There is a way to do that in windows form application somehow?
And if there is a way ,please explain me how to do that.

Thank you,
Asaf.

Comment: When you say "wave", are you talking about something like a sine wave for instance?

Comment: I mean to zigzag line but with rounded corners

Comment: A picture or sketch goes a long way into understanding what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

Create a brush as follows

```
Brush zigzagBrush = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.HatchBrush(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.HatchStyle.ZigZag, Color.Black);
```

You can then draw the line using the above brush

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
this.createGraphics.drawLines(new Point[]{});
```

where the point array contains your line corners.

Comment: There is no way to draw is more like a wave? or to make a wave i have to draw allot of pictures?

Comment: For a wave, you could do the same with this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/3w58chwy.aspx :)